# Unique number to be used as ID across all classes in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, uniqueidentifier

I have an application that runs several asynchronous methods to create messages that are sent with a unique id to a remote host.

Two types of messages are being created in two separate classes. One class is inherited from the other but the shared methods are shadowed meaning they are different.

I would like the ID to be an incremented integer.

Does anyone have a good way of accomplishing this task? I have looked up the use of static numbers and class generated ids but they don't cover the shared method issue.

I am also aware of a single shared method being able to use a static number but that doesn't help when my method is shadowed.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but you should add some code to show what you've done so far and explaining why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some single-instance way of doing this.
VB.NET natural way would be using Module:

```
Module IDHelper

    Private fLastID As Integer

    Public Function NextMessageID() As Integer
        Return Threading.Interlocked.Increment(fLastID)
    End Function

End Module
```

Nice way of doing this is using singleton. Or somehing like that. But your original idea with shared member works as well. Problem could be in missing synchronization.

```
Public Class Base

    Private Shared fLastID As Integer

    Protected Function NextMessageID() As Integer
        Return Threading.Interlocked.Increment(fLastID)
    End Function

    Public Function CreateMessage() As String
        Return "Base message is " & NextMessageID()
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Inherited
    Inherits Base

    Public Shadows Function CreateMessage() As String
        Return "Inherited message is " & NextMessageID()
    End Function

End Class
```

Shadowing functions is almost never a good idea. Overriding is the good way to go.

Comment: From my understanding overriding is not possible with a shared method. Is this not accurate? VS definitely steers you in this direction.

Comment: Shadows is usefull only when you have no control about the base class and you can't mark the base method as Overridable. When you have control over the base method, then you should mark your base method as Overridable and your inherited method as Overrides.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed the ID to also be shared so it would share across all classes too instead of my two methods generating the ID independently and being aware of the others current ID number.

Code

```
Public Property MessageID As Long
Private Shared NextID As Long = 0

Public Shared Function GenerateNextID() As Long
    NextID += 1
    Return NextID
End Function
```